# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [799996, 199999]

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, train-test-split

I am splitting a single df so why is it giving Inconsistent no of samples in X_train, X_test (if that is what the error means)?

```
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(df[categorical_cols+ numeric_cols], test_size=0.2, random_state=4)
regression = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, X_test)
regression.score(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the method will do something roughly equivalent to the following:

1. Generate a random number between 0 and 1 for each record
2. Put records where the random number is below .2 in the test set
3. Put the rest in the training set

There is some randomness to how many actually get put in the train/test sets because the number of random numbers under .2 won't always be exactly 20%.

Comment: Thanks - I understand how that parameter works now.
that leaves the question, how do you get equal splits? especially when your data has an uneven no of records?

Comment: Specify test_size = 200000 for example. If you give it an integer, it will give you that number in the test set.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It uses the remainder of the data as train
I resolved the problem by using train_size=400000,test_size=400000

Comment: I understand now. I didn't realize you wanted to have the train and test data be the same number of records. That isn't normally needed. Depending on how much data I have, I use anywhere between a 70/30 and 90/10 split. I prefer as much training data as I can get so I split so that I have just enough test data to be credible. Best wishes!

Comment: if i didn't have them the same i was getting the error - or was it caused by something else?

Comment: It's caused by something else. Where you have X_test in the LinearRegression method, you should have the training labels. Then you would use the predict_proba method with input X_test.